# python 対象の行と次の行について計算をする

Tags: python

```
data
a 100 200
b 250 400
c 600 1200
```

このようなデータがあるときに
リストに1行目の"a 100 200"と2行目の"b 250 400"を入れ、
"a-b:50(250-200)"という計算をした後にリストを空にしたいです。

どのような処理をしたらいいでしょうか？

readlineを使ってリストに入れたのですが、次の行をどのように指定していいかわかりません。
アドバイスお願いいたします。

Comment: 聞きたいことは、リストにおいて次の行（次のデータ）を指定する方法でしょうか？data = [['a',100,200],['b',250,400],['c',600,1200]] とあった時にdata[1]ということでしょうか？聞きたいことをもう少し整理して記載して頂けますと回答も集まるかと思います。

Comment: [あわせて読みたい](https://teratail.com/questions/178532)

Answer (score 1):

おそらく`for`文で指定行の次の行を取得したいと推測して回答いたします。
`a-b`ではなく`b-a`と表示したいような気がしますが、サンプルコードは質問に沿った出力を行います。

readlineを使ってリストに入れたならば、リスト変数に対して`list[i+1]のように指定行の次のインデックスを指定して次の行を取得できます。

メモリ使用量は増えますが、`zip`関数を使ってn行目とn+1行目を並行してループすることもできます。

リストを空にする関数として`clear()`が用意されています。

蛇足とは思います(しかもコードが汚いです)が、`pandas`の`concat`, `shift`を駆使することで差分も自動計算できます。

```
import os

file_name = "data" 
# 下準備(テスト用ファイル作成)
with open(file_name, "w") as f:
    f.write("a 100 200\nb 250 400\nc 600 1200")

list = []
with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    print(u"for文でリスト作成")
    for line in f:
        ss = line[:-1].split(" ")
        list.append(ss)

    print(u"リストのインデックスを使用する")
    size = len(list)
    for i in range(size - 1):
        c, n = list[i], list[i+1] #current, next
        print("{}-{}:{}({}-{})".format(c[0], n[0], int(n[1]) - int(c[2]), n[1], c[2]))

    print(u"zipでリストを回す")
    for c, n in zip(list[:-1], list[1:]):
        print("{}-{}:{}({}-{})".format(c[0], n[0], int(n[1]) - int(c[2]), n[1], c[2]))

print(u"リストを空にする")
list.clear()
print(list)

# pandasが入っていない場合はここから下を削除して実行すること
print(u"pandasを使う")
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, delimiter="\s+")
ct = pd.concat([df, df.shift(), df - df.shift().shift(-1, axis=1)], axis=1)
for r in ct[1:].iterrows():
    t, v1, v2 = r[1][0], r[1][1], r[1][2]
    print("{}-{}:{}({}-{})".format(t.iat[1], t.iat[0], int(v1.iat[2]), int(v1.iat[0]), int(v2.iat[1])))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。１つ質問させてください。 size = len(list)
    for i in range(size - 1):の使い方（なぜlenを測る必要があるのか）が理解できないので教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: 質問の文意の通り、1行目と2行目**のみ**取得することが目的であるならば、`len`関数も不要です。今回のサンプルコードは複数行に渡ってn行目とn+1行目を同時に取得するために最も簡易的な方法の例として`len`を使ったコードを提示しています。`len`は解決方法の一つですので、`for (i, item) in enumerate(list):`のような形で`len`を使わないこともできます(実際zip関数やpandasを使うコードでは`size`変数を使用しません)。もし「`len`使わなくても○○すればできるのに、なんでこの人`len`なんて使ってるの？」という別の解法があるならば、それが正答です。ぜひ上記の正答を回答として投稿し、自己回答を[承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)してください！きっと今後同じようなことで悩んだ人の役に立ちます！！